# SQL: count occurencies per value, if not 3, then duplicate value with unique id

Tags: sql, magento

I am having some problems with a Magento database, and need some help.

A table where videos are stored in, have 3 rows per video; one per store language.

The video values should therefore be added 3 times when I add a video to the website. However, about 1500 products only have videos for 1 or 2 languages.

Is there a way to check the table with a query and count if a value has 3 occurencies, and if not, duplicate the value with a unique store id (1-2-3)?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the unique composite index in several columns of your table, in the same way you can use count () in the sub query to know how many records you have store.